# Reading video files one by one from a directory in python

Tags: python, opencv

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 with opencv 3.1.0 and python 3.5. I installed it by using a tutorial in this link https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/10/24/ubuntu-16-04-how-to-install-opencv/. Then I tried to use this code to read video files and it worked once but then I did some changes which now I am not able to figure out. Because it worked once I don't think it will be a problem of  FFmpeg installation which is suggested in most of the results I found. What can be the problem or is there any other way to read and then process video files one by one.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from imutils.video import FileVideoStream
from glob import glob

img_mask = '/home/esrt/Desktop/images/*.mov'
img_names = glob(img_mask)
for fn in img_names:
    start = '/home/esrt/Desktop/images/'
    s = fn
    print((s.split(start))[1])
    filename_1 = (s.split(start))[1]
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(filename_1)
    while (True):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if ret== False:
            print("False")
            break
        else:
            cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
            key = cv2.waitKey(25)
            cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/version-control/intro-to-version-control.html

Comment: your filename_1 will be video_name.mov without full file path. if your video and python file are not in same directory, it will fail. may be you want cap=cv2.VideoCapture(os.path.join(start, filename_1)) or in this case, simply cap=cv2.VideoCapture(start+filename_1). But you should also report what error you are geting.

Comment: Look at it line by line. Does it still iterate through the directory? Does it process the files?

Answer (score 1):

Posting the error you received would help me determine the issue in your code. Though the loop below will allow you to access the video files you want to.

Put video_dir of where the files are located.

```
for entry in os.listdir(video_dir):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(video_dir, entry)):
    print(entry)
```